# is that possible to import / migrate the logs from existing application insights to new application insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights, powerbi-desktop, bot-framework-composer

How to import / migrate the logs from existing application insights to new application insights ?

With an existing application insights, I'm creating report in powerbi dashboard. If switched to new application insights, how to import the data from existing to new application insights? Or can we generate report with multiple application insights ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kusto supports cross-app queries:

```
union app("ai1").requests, app("ai2").requests
| count
```

See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query